# How to add a specific time period to indicators?

Tags: pine-script

I have created a code to help me plot some lines that I always use for intraday trading in TradingView. However, when I want to add the time specific criteria to the indicators, it shows error like this:

> Mismatched input '0500-1559' expecting ')'.

And after I have changed the code according to the error, it comes out with this funny error:

> Mismatched input ')' expecting ')'.

Did anyone face such a problem before? How could I possibly solve it?
Below is the example of the code that I had created before:

```
//@version=4    
study("Important Intraday Lines", overlay=true)

// Grab the lines for the ticker    
PDH = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",high,time("today"'0500-1559',or,[1]'1600-0459')

// Plot the lines    
plot(PDH, title="High",color=color.red,linewidth=2,trackprice=true, offset = -9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `security()` and `time()` functions are quite wrong.

The fourth argument of `security()` is `gaps` but you are passing time.

> gaps (const bool) Merge strategy for the requested data (requested
> data automatically merges with the main series OHLC data). Possible
> values: barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.gaps_off. barmerge.gaps_on -
> requested data is merged with possible gaps (na values).
> barmerge.gaps_off - requested data is merged continuously without
> gaps, all the gaps are filled with the previous nearest existing
> values. Default value is barmerge.gaps_off.

For example:

```
s2=security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(s2)
```

Your use of `time()` is completely wrong.

It is hard to tell what you are trying to do but I recommend you read the user manual first before trying to code something.

Read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) for the `security()`, and [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html) for `time()`.

Comment: Thanks for the information!


I actually wanted to add a "Previous Day High" line to my chart. 

I want it to refer to the latest candle formed, '0500-1559' when the market is closed, and refer to the previous candle, '1600-0459' when there is pre-market data and when market is opened.


As according to my current script (without the time function), it automatically refers to the latest candle. Eg: it refers to today's candle high instead of previous day high when the market is opened.